# JxMap where default folder when browser.loadURL called?

Tags: java, netbeans, jxbrowser

I follow the tutorial from 
https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000012874-google-maps

i already create 2 file.

1.map.html

2.GoogleMapsSample.java

when i run the program i get an error "This webpage is not found". I think this is because the code

```
browser.loadURL("map.html");
```

When i change the "map.html" into "http://www.google.com" it's working.

so , my question is where i must put the map.html ?

i already try put in root project, same package it's not working.

I using netbean 8.1

thank you before.

Comment: Only to be sure. Have you replaced the `API_KEY` in the url `...key=API_KEY&...` with your API key? Following the [Goole tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) the parameter `sensor` is not needed anymore. And after reading it. It seems the `map.html` should look different for current API version. (check the `Hello World` example on the same page).

Comment: Yes i already put the API_KEY. I already request it from google. My question is how to load `map.html` ? where i should put it in my project ? Because when i change `browser.loadUrl` into `browser.loadHTML` and i put the html code into there it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this [post](https://dzone.com/articles/google-maps-java-swing) you might need to add the path to the file.

> browser.loadURL("C:\\map.html");

If this is still not working.